# Replacing regex with italic code in Vim for Latex

Tags: vimscript, replace, plugin-vim-latex

I am using vim to write a document in Latex.
I have to replace a regex with the italic code, which is `\textit{regex}`.
I use the Vim code:

```
:%s/regex/\textit\{regex\}/g
```

But the `\t` expression is interpreted as a tab.

Would anyone know how to input `\textit{}` in the vim replace tool, without having `\t` interpreted as a tab?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `\`.

`:%s/regex/\\textit\{regex\}/g`

You'll have more information about what to put in the second part of the substitute command by using:

`:help substitute`

Comment: I though this command was not working, for Vim display the words directly in italic.
But it is indeed working well. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :-) Thanks for Nice words

Comment: @Drosera_capensis Welcome to the site! Quick suggestion: if this answer solves your problem, you should upvote and accept it, by clicking on the upwards-pointing triangle and the checkmark to the left of the answer.